How do I pass an argument (e.g., filename with path) to Avisynth script
Please help how to pass an argument (e.g., filename with fullpath) to Avisynth script.
Subj taken from answer https://stackoverflow.com/users/63733/marapet to following question:
Creating multiple videos with Avisynth
I have no idea how to pass an argument to script.

We aren't here to tell you how to run a script; we help to fix a reproducible issue with your submitted code. Perhaps you could get some assistance by making a comment in an appropriate location within your linked question.

Either generate a new avs script with this info inside or use a plugin to read the environment.

I'm not sure what kind of answer you're expecting.  The question you linked to already explains that passing arguments is not possible, and it has answers that show you how to generate scripts instead.

To pass an argument to a batch script you use:
call <filename>.bat <arguments>
For example:
example.bat
echo %~1

To call it you use:
call example.bat "text"
To start a program with arguments you use:
start <program filepath and name with file extension> <arguments>

This is not applicable to AviSynth scripts.  AviSynth scripts are not executable; they are files that are opened in media players/editors.  Passing arguments to an AviSynth script is not possible.
